# Создание кастомного отображения объектов в виде карточек

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Всем привет.
Решил заморочиться на счет отображения списка объектов в виде карточек, но что то не получается ничего нагуглить.
[image: Скрин окна]

Так выглядит окно приложения, идет отображение объектов в ListView

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Animals}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnimal}" 
                  MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:AnimalCard MinWidth="200" MinHeight="200"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Мне хочется что бы объекты располагались в одной строке по очереди и если кончалось место, то переносились на новую строку. Не знаю какой контрол может мне с этим помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось разобраться.

```
    <ListView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnimal}"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:AnimalCard Width="230" Height="230"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

Таким образом теперь выглядит код с отображением коллекции.

[image: Окно]

Так выглядит окно приложения.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй WrapPanel

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AnimalsList}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Animal}" Height="100"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

[Подробнее о WrapPanel](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/4.6.php)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]